# pixel perfect 3 column select elements in a row

Tags: html, css

If div it will be no problem achieving a responsive 3 column but in my case it's div, I'm having problem to achieve pixel perfect 3 column with `<select>` within a row.

```css
.row{
display:table;
   width:100%;
   background: #eee;
}
.slct{
    border:1px solid #000;
    display:table-cell;
    width:31%;
    margin: 0 2% 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
                <select class="slct " id="ppax">
                    <option value="1">Date *</option>
                    <option value="2">3/3/2015</option>
                    <option value="2">4/3/2015</option>
                </select>
                
                <select class="slct " id="ppax">
                    <option value="1">Time *</option>
                    <option value="2">11:30 AM</option>
                    <option value="2">12:00 AM</option>
                    <option value="2">12:30 AM</option>
                </select>

                    <select class="slct " id="ppax">
                    <option value="1">1 pax</option>
                    <option value="2">2 pax</option>
                    <option value="3">3 pax</option>
                    <option value="4">4 pax</option>
                    <option value="5">5 pax</option>
                    <option value="5">6 pax</option>
                    <option value="5">7 pax</option>
                    <option value="5">8 pax</option>
                    <option value="5">9 pax</option>
                    <option value="5">10 pax</option>
                </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I think use following css will solve your issue:  `.row {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eee;
    display: table;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}

.slct {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 34%;
}`

Comment: @ketan I want the margin. If without margin I can hardcoded the pixels

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit, this was a hard one. Percentage can be used when you have a defined parent. Because body doesn't have and will never have a fixed width or height, when dealing with it it's easier to use `vw` and `vh`.

So here is the CSS that will help you out:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.row{
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #eee;
}

.slct{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc((100vw / 3 - 6px) - 2vw);
  width: -moz-calc((100vw / 3 - 6px) - 2vw);
  margin: 0 2vw 10px 0;
}
```